# Call declined on Android 11

Tags: notifications, calls

I got a very strange situation when on Android 11 I got call declined. The caller is in favorites, did not set any filtering. This happen after 23:30h (11:30 PM). The problem is not in lost of mobile coverage because I see in the calls log record for this declined call.

The phone is OnePlus 8T, I do not subscribe for beta of Carrier Services app (it's stock app as provided by manufacturer). I have no firewall (for calls) installed or any app which can be related to this issue.

Sleeping is not activated. People - Calls is set to Starred contacts and this contact (with declined call) is starred.

My humble suspicion is some power management (during call-in the consumption of phones is quite high) settings need to be configured to **avoid this to happen again**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the setting for Do Not Disturb mode: 1) Schedules, some phones have "Sleeping" by default, also check its time period, and 2) People - Calls, check if it's "None" or "Starred contacts" already.